# Sending civiMail through Amazon SES

Tags: civimail, mosaico, amazon

I'm using civiCRM 5.21.0 and Wordpress 5.3.2
I'm trying to send civiMail bulk email sending through Amazon SES. I configured and activated SMTP credentials in civiCRM settings. 
The test mail works fine (email sent throuhg Aamazon SES); I can also send individual mails effectively.
I used a gsuite email adresse as bounced email. From the log, Fetch Bounces cron jobs apparently works. 
When I'm trying to use CiviMail to send bulk mails (and mosaico as a template builder), they're not sent (although the corresponding cron job is triggered correctly). 
Looking in ConfigAndLog I read the following error:

```
[error] Ignoring exception thrown by nullHandler: 10001, Failed to connect to ssl://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused (code: -1, response: )]
```

Thanks for your help!!

Here is the debug log :

```
[debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(919): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::nullHandler(Object(PEAR_Error))
#2 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(577): PEAR_Error->__construct("Failed to connect to ssl://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465 [SMTP: Fail...", 10001, 16, (Array:2), NULL)
#3 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(236): PEAR::_raiseError(NULL, "Failed to connect to ssl://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465 [SMTP: Fail...", 10001)
#4 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/mail/Mail/smtp.php(397): PEAR::__callStatic("raiseError", (Array:2))
#5 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/mail/Mail/smtp.php(279): Mail_smtp->getSMTPObject()
#6 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/mail/Mail/smtp.php(266): Mail_smtp->send_or_fail("<laurent.arnoult@parlemonde.org>", (Array:11), "--=_5b439487a1c6a51ee03f531590ef1bb1\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\nConten...")
#7 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.flexmailer/src/Listener/DefaultSender.php(58): Mail_smtp->send("<laurent.arnoult@parlemonde.org>", (Array:11), "--=_5b439487a1c6a51ee03f531590ef1bb1\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\nConten...")
#8 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(184): Civi\FlexMailer\Listener\DefaultSender->onSend(Object(Civi\FlexMailer\Event\SendBatchEvent), "civi.flexmailer.send", Object(Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher))
#9 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(46): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch((Array:1), "civi.flexmailer.send", Object(Civi\FlexMailer\Event\SendBatchEvent))
#10 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(47): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch("civi.flexmailer.send", Object(Civi\FlexMailer\Event\SendBatchEvent))
#11 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.flexmailer/src/FlexMailer.php(222): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch("civi.flexmailer.send", Object(Civi\FlexMailer\Event\SendBatchEvent))
#12 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.flexmailer/src/FlexMailer.php(159): Civi\FlexMailer\FlexMailer->fireSendBatch((Array:1))
#13 [internal function](): Civi\FlexMailer\FlexMailer->Civi\FlexMailer\{closure}((Array:1))
#14 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.flexmailer/src/Event/WalkBatchesEvent.php(55): call_user_func(Object(Closure), (Array:1))
#15 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.flexmailer/src/Listener/DefaultBatcher.php(71): Civi\FlexMailer\Event\WalkBatchesEvent->visit((Array:1))
#16 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(184): Civi\FlexMailer\Listener\DefaultBatcher->onWalk(Object(Civi\FlexMailer\Event\WalkBatchesEvent), "civi.flexmailer.walk", Object(Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher))
#17 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(46): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch((Array:1), "civi.flexmailer.walk", Object(Civi\FlexMailer\Event\WalkBatchesEvent))
#18 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(47): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch("civi.flexmailer.walk", Object(Civi\FlexMailer\Event\WalkBatchesEvent))
#19 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.flexmailer/src/FlexMailer.php(196): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch("civi.flexmailer.walk", Object(Civi\FlexMailer\Event\WalkBatchesEvent))
#20 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.flexmailer/src/FlexMailer.php(161): Civi\FlexMailer\FlexMailer->fireWalkBatches(Object(Closure))
#21 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.flexmailer/src/FlexMailer.php(122): Civi\FlexMailer\FlexMailer->run()
#22 [internal function](): Civi\FlexMailer\FlexMailer::createAndRun(Object(CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob), Object(Mail_smtp), NULL)
#23 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Resolver.php(119): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:3))
#24 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php(180): Civi\Core\Resolver->call("\Civi\FlexMailer\FlexMailer::createAndRun", (Array:3))
#25 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php(2784): CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob::runJobs(NULL, NULL)
#26 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(345): CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing::processQueue()
#27 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(85): civicrm_api3_job_process_mailing((Array:1))
#28 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(152): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#29 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(83): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:9))
#30 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("job", "process_mailing", (Array:1), NULL)
#31 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(133): civicrm_api("job", "process_mailing", (Array:1))
#32 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(66): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJob(Object(CRM_Core_ScheduledJob))
#33 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(118): CRM_Core_JobManager->execute(FALSE)
#34 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(85): civicrm_api3_job_execute((Array:2))
#35 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(152): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#36 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(83): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:9))
#37 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("job", "execute", (Array:2), NULL)
#38 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/wp-cli/civicrm.php(202): civicrm_api("job", "execute", (Array:2))
#39 /home/parlemon/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/wp-cli/civicrm.php(153): CiviCRM_Command->api()
#40 [internal function](): CiviCRM_Command->__invoke((Array:2), (Array:0))
#41 phar:///home/parlemon/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Dispatcher/CommandFactory.php(98): call_user_func((Array:2), (Array:3), (Array:0))
#42 [internal function](): WP_CLI\Dispatcher\CommandFactory::WP_CLI\Dispatcher\{closure}((Array:3), (Array:0))
#43 phar:///home/parlemon/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Dispatcher/Subcommand.php(451): call_user_func(Object(Closure), (Array:3), (Array:0))
#44 phar:///home/parlemon/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(371): WP_CLI\Dispatcher\Subcommand->invoke((Array:3), (Array:0), (Array:0))
#45 phar:///home/parlemon/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(394): WP_CLI\Runner->run_command((Array:4), (Array:0))
#46 phar:///home/parlemon/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1160): WP_CLI\Runner->run_command_and_exit()
#47 phar:///home/parlemon/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(23): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#48 phar:///home/parlemon/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(74): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process(Object(WP_CLI\Bootstrap\BootstrapState))
#49 phar:///home/parlemon/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#50 phar:///home/parlemon/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include("phar:///home/parlemon/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php")
#51 /home/parlemon/bin/wp(4): include("phar:///home/parlemon/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php")
```

Comment: Just confirming that sending works correctly with a traditional bulk email but not with a Mosaico one - sorry not quite clear from your question.

Comment: Actually I had not tested before your message! Just did test with the traditional bulk email... Not working either. Exact same error log. Meanwhile, I also realized that the only user (myself) belonging to the group I was trying to send bulk message to, had been removed from this group.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the from email address your email is coming from has been whitelisted by Amazon SES?

Comment: Yes, I'm sending from a verified email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me recommend you [this great extension](https://github.com/mecachisenros/aws) (compatible with Mosaico, just empty CiviCRM cache before creating a new mailing). Worked for me! Allow you to handle bounces, AND track clicks & open mails through Amazon AWS. :-)